# URL attribute in document object of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have browsed `google.com` and checked the "URL" property of `document` object of JavaScript in browser console.

```
> documentNode = window["Document"]
       [object Function]
> obj = documentNode();
      [object XMLDocument]
> obj["URL"]
     "about:blank"
```

I am expecting `google.com` as the output, when I type `obj["URL"]`.

If my understanding is correct, Please let me know, why the above output says "about:blank"?

Comment: window.location.href

Answer (score 4):

By executing `obj = documentNode();` you are creating a new instance of a `Document`.

This means `obj` and `window.document` are both instances of `Document`, but they each have a unique instance with unique property values.

Try `console.log(window.document.URL)` - you should see the URL you were expecting.

Comment: `obj = window["document"];
[object HTMLDocument]
obj["URL"];
"https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl"` How can write single expression to get URL? am using firefox browser

Comment: if you just want the url of the current page, use `window.location.href`.

Comment: I repeat, Using dictionary notation in my previous comment, how do I write single expression?

Comment: umm.. `window['location']['href']`

Comment: `window["document"]["URL"]` works. I am not sure, why are you preferring `window['location']['href']`?

Comment: @overexchange `document.URL` can only be retrieved, not set.  `window.location.href` can be both retrieved AND set.  The unspoken standard is to always use `window.location.href`.  It's very rare to see people using `document.URL`